# Incorrect data types for a transposed mixed type DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having difficulty with the data types of a transposed dataframe.

The example below is adapted from the [`DataFrame.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) documentation. The integer type of the `kids` column is maintained in the transposed dataframe, as shown in the docs.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Alice', 'Bob'],
... 'score': [9.5, 8.6],
... 'employed': [False, True],
... 'kids': [5, 6]})
>>> df
    name  score  employed  kids
0  Alice    9.5     False     5
1    Bob    8.6      True     6
>>> df.T
              0     1
name      Alice   Bob
score       9.5   8.6
employed  False  True
kids          5     6
```

However, if I remove two of the columns so that there is only a float type column and an integer type column, all of the values in the transposed dataframe get converted to float.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'score': [9.5, 8.6],
... 'kids': [5, 6]}).T
         0    1
score  9.5  8.6
kids   5.0  6.0
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) you provided the answer to why is at the bottom

> When the DataFrame has mixed dtypes, we get a transposed DataFrame with the object dtype

in your case it's `int` and `float` making the "parent" type float so everything converts to a float

As for preventing, not really, unless your ok with object dtype, this is a work around

```
df
    name  score  employed  kids
0  Alice    9.5     False     5
1    Bob    8.6      True     6

print(df.T.drop(['name', 'employed']))
```

```
         0    1
score  9.5  8.6
kids     5    6
```

The [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/62a87bf4a2af02a8d3bc271ad26e5994292b8e6a/pandas/core/frame.py#L2675-L2771) also explains this fact, however I can't seem to find a reason as to why

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something fundamental about how pandas and numpy work. Why is a column of int considered to be closer enough to float that the type of the whole structure becomes float...? Or in other words, why isn't this considered a mixed type df? Isn't int its own separate dtype from float...?